# What should be Switch Mediator's source path?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I've two XML-based data files, I need to use a `switch mediator` in my API to direct the xml file to its respective mediation flow which is implemented in the same API. The XMLs are shown below:

**XML - 1**

```
<Table>
     <Trademarks>
          <FileNbr>574988</FileNbr>
          <DateOfRegistration>03-DEC-21</DateOfRegistration>
          <Class> 43 </Class>
          <ApplicantName>Ramada International, Inc.</ApplicantName>
          <Address>22 Sylvan Way Parsippany, New Jersey  07054</Address>
          <Title>RAMADA RESIDENCES</Title>
          <Status>Trademark registered</Status>
     </Trademarks>
     <Trademarks>
          <FileNbr>524918</FileNbr>
          <DateOfRegistration>03-DEC-21</DateOfRegistration>
          <Class> 37 </Class>
          <ApplicantName>Muhammad Usman, Trading as, IMAMDIN ASSOCIATES</ApplicantName>
          <Address>Imamdin Associates, 89/6-R,</Address>
          <Title>IMAM DIN</Title>
          <Status>Trademark registered</Status>
     </Trademarks>
</Table>
```

**XML - 2**

```
<Table>
     <Copyright>
          <applicationno>1641/2001</applicationno>
          <applicationdate>11/15/2001 12:00:00 AM</applicationdate>
          <TitleEnglish>DURA PLUS</TitleEnglish>
          <applicantname>FARMIGEA PAKISTAN (PVT) LTD.</applicantname>
          <class>ARTISTIC WORK</class>
          <City>LAHORE</City>
          <Country>PAKISTAN</Country>
          <status>Application Registered</status>
     </Copyright>
     <Copyright>
          <applicationno>1644/2001</applicationno>
          <applicationdate>11/15/2001 12:00:00 AM</applicationdate>
          <TitleEnglish>OCUGEL FARMIGEA</TitleEnglish>
          <applicantname>FARMIGEA PAKISTAN (PVT) LTD.</applicantname>
          <class>ARTISTIC WORK</class>
          <City>LAHORE</City>
          <Country>PAKISTAN</Country>
          <status>Application Registered</status>
     </Copyright>
</Table>
```

**Question**

1. I need to specify the `Source XPath` for the `Switch mediator`. In
   the above scenario how can I differentiate between the two XML data files
   based on the second nodes i-e **Trademarks** & **Copyright.**?
2. Which property should I used for the above requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xpath `local-name()` function, like below. **But keep in mind, that only checks the first element after `<Table>`.** I also like to use `upper-case()` function, to avoid upper/lower case issues. And the cases are with regex start `^` and end `$` matches. Working example below.

```
<switch source="upper-case(local-name(//Table/*))" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
    <case regex="^TRADEMARKS$">
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"Trademarks":"DoSomething"}</format>
        </payloadFactory>
    </case>
    <case regex="^COPYRIGHT$">
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"Copyright":"To something else"}</format>
        </payloadFactory>
    </case>
    <default>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"Error":"Invalid table name"}</format>
        </payloadFactory>
    </default>
</switch>
<respond/>
```